# Concept Check: Number of ways to have a single pair in a 5-hand deck?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

Combinations haven't quite clicked for me yet. The logic behind them doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

My question is, why is the answer to this
$$_{13} C_{1}\cdot _{4} C_{2} \cdot _{12} C_{3} \cdot 4^3$$

Why, for example, can't it be $_{52} C_{2} \cdot _{48} C_{3}$?   For the pair, you need two out of 52 cards, then you can only choose 3 out of the remaining 48 cards... But of course this is the wrong answer. But why is that...?

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution does not count the right thing. You can't choose *any* two cards out of 52, they must be of the same value. The remaining three cards must be different values from the first two, as well as eachother.

$$_{13}C_1  \text{ ways to choose the value of the card}$$

$$_{4}C_2  \text{ ways to choose 2 of the four cards of that value}$$

$$_{12}C_3  \text{ ways to choose the values of remaining different cards}$$

$$4 \text{ ways to choose the suit of each of the remaining 3 cards}$$

Comment: Interesting. Now that makes sense when you explain it. But still at the same time... What if you consider that you choose the 3 cards that aren't part of the pair first. Then would it still be 13 choose 1 for way to choose the kind of the paid?

Comment: We're counting combinations, order does not matter.   Choosing the three different cards first, we have
 $$_{13}C_{3} \cdot 4^3\cdot  _{10}C_1 \cdot _4C_2$$